# Push arrays in one object with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array:

```
var arr = [scanner, monitor];
```

And then I have these lines of code,

```js
var arr = ["scanner", "monitor"];
var newArr = [];

for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ ) {
  newArr.push({"techName":[{"id":i,"name": "name"+i }]});
}
console.log(newArr);
```

which generate this object:

```
[
  {
    "techName0": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "name0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "techName1": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "name1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And I want to create an object with arrays like these:

```
{
    "techName0": [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "name0"
    }],
    "techName1": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name1"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You can't have same key more than once in a single object.

Comment: You already have `techName` as an array of objects, so why do you want two `techName`'s? (Not that you could, as Usman says above.)

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense. What would `newArr.techName` give you if you could have two keys with the same name but different values?

Comment: May be instead of techName you want have "scanner" : ... and "monitor"...?

Comment: Please provide us with a [MCVE] so that we are able to understand what you are trying to achieve and be able to be of help.

Comment: @Barrosy I'd argue that an example isn't needed here. There already is an example. There is a reproducable code, too. But the *expectation* makes no sense. An example is good if it's clear what the problem is but not where it occurs, e.g., `foo(1)` produces `4` instead of `2` but there is no code for `foo`.

Comment: @Mohammad Usman: "You can't have same key more than once in a single object.", yes my mistake. I forgot the numbers.

Comment: Please read up what MVCE actually stands for @VLAZ

Comment: @Barrosy there is no need for snark - I know what it stands for. I am saying it doesn't make sense here - if OP *did* have the code that produces what they want, (reproducible example), then they *wouldn't have a question*. If they have some code that has an issue, then that would work. And they do have code that is minimal, it's complete, it's verifiable. But doesn't do what they want. How could they supply *different* code that covers all these parameters and somehow clarifies the question without also solving it?

Comment: Perhaps by providing an explanation to the code provided, why the output is required to be the way OP is expecting it to be. This would result in a bit more **complete**ness.

Comment: @Barrosy that's not what "complete" stands for. It's supposed to be self-contained, that's it. The question should provide all the information for somebody to reproduce the problem. And it *does*. The expectation is NOT part of the example, though - if somebody says "when I do 2 + 2 I get 4, but I want to get yellow" we do have a complete example. The question makes no sense without clarification. So, it falls under "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry OP, you should not try to add an MCVE to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var arr = ["scanner", "monitor"];

const output = arr.reduce((acc, name, id) => (acc[`techName${id}`] = [{ id, name }], acc), {});

console.log(output);
```